# UserControl with multiple TextBoxes' that aggregate into a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding, ip-address, dependency-properties

I'm trying to build a UserControl that is essentially an IPv4 Address 'text box'.

In the UserControl there are 4 TextBoxes, with a TextBlock containing a single "." between each TextBox:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="GroupA" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="GroupA" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="GroupA" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="GroupA" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" TabIndex="0" x:Name="TextOctet1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="." />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" TabIndex="1" x:Name="TextOctet2" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="." />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="4" TabIndex="2" x:Name="TextOctet3" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="." />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="6" TabIndex="3" x:Name="TextOctet4" />
</Grid>
```

My hope is that I can have a DependencyProperty called IPAddress on the control that I can bind to, or set a default value in XAML  "123.123.123.123".

```
<local:IPBox IPAddress="123.123.123.123" />
```

I thought that I could use something like MultiBinding and an IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class IPAddressConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)value).Split('.');
    }
}
```

But I believe that would be doing the opposite of what I want. A MultiValueConverter would merge multiple business logic properties into a single property for a TextBox to bind to.

Instead, I want to bind a single business logic property (a string representing an IPv4 Address) and have each Octet show up in its own TextBox. Then if any of the Octet TextBoxes change, the IPAddress dependency property will update.

Is this possible? Am I thinking about this problem in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  One's simply to create private properties for the octet and bind the text boxes to those properties, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding RelativeSource={AncestorType UserControl}, Path=Octet1}, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

and then implement setters that update the dependency property:

```
private int _Octet1;
private int Octet1
{
   get { return _Octet1; }
   set
   {
     _Octet1 = value;
     UpdateIPAddress();
   }
}

private void UpdateIPAddress()
{
   IPAddress = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", _Octet1, _Octet2, _Octet3, _Octet4);
}
```

**Edit:**

Two-way binding is a little tricky because you need change notification in order to update the UI.  The way I'd handle this, probably, is to create a view model class that has octet and IP address properties and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then create an instance of it in the UserControl's constructor and bind all the UI controls to the properties.  That way when the `IPAddress` on the view model gets set, the setter can parse the value, update the octet properties, and they raise `PropertyChanged` and the UI gets updated.

Then in the `UserControl`, I'd handle `PropertyChanged` on the view model and set the `IPAddress` dependency property on the *control* when the `IPAddress1` property on the *view model* changes.  (That isn't as weird as it sounds.)

You'll also need to write a function that sets the view model's `IPAddress` property to the value of the `IPAddress` dependency property, and set that function as a callback when you 
register the DP.

So the chain of events will be:  something sets the `IPAddress` property on the control -> the DP callback sets the `IPAddress` property on the view model -> the `IPAddress` setter parses the octets and sets the `Octet` properties -> the `Octet` properties raise `PropertyChanged` -> binding pushes the changed values out to the UI controls in your `UserControl`.  Going the other way, it's:  user enters an octet -> octet setter sets `IPAddress` on the view model -> user control handles `PropertyChanged` and sets the `IPAddress` dependency property.

Comment: So if I bind my UserControl's IPAddress dependency property to some correctly formatted string, how do the Octets get updated? (two way binding):

<local:IPBox IPAddress="123.123.123.123" />

Comment: Then I think you need to implement a view model.  See my edit.

Comment: Ha... so I had tried all of this stuff the first time... and it just wouldn't work. I later find out that having default data in my dp was causing it to appear blank when I bound to data that was already the same value as the default data: *public static readonly DependencyProperty IPAddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IPAddress", typeof(string), typeof(IPBox), new UIPropertyMetadata("0.0.0.0", new PropertyChangedCallback(IPAddressChanged)));*. As soon as I removed "0.0.0.0", everything started working. Thanks for taking the time to look at this and help me out!